# Bootstrap: glyphicon-triangle-bottom not displaying

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a a simple instance of the bootstrap glyphicon-triangle-bottom 
Placed in my rails view which I cannot get to display. It was working with a different glyphicon but not with this one.

```
#who_we_are  
  .text#who_text
    =link_to(who_we_are_path) do 
      %h2
        =t 'who_we_are_header'
      %p
        =t 'who_we_are'
      .glyphicon.glyphicon-triangle-bottom
```

Comment: What Bootstrap version are you using ?

Comment: @dyaa bootstrap/sass 3.1.1 which I imagine uses Bootstrap 3?

Comment: when looking through my `application.css` that my Rails app compiles, i don't see any css relating to `triangle-bottom` but i *do* see the css for the other glyphicons that do show up. Is there a way to add the `triangle-bottom` to my library somehow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Bootstrap glyphicon-triangle-bottom is available in the Version 3.3.3.