# Reducing TH-Tags with ngRepeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is the currently section of TH-Tags in the view:

```
...
    <th>
        <a href="" ng-click="sortReverse = !sortReverse; order('fname',sortReverse)">
        Firstname
        <span ng-show="sortType=='fname' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
        <span ng-show="sortType=='fname' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"></span>
        </a>
    </th>
...
```

And that was my first solution but it doesn't work:

```
<th ng-repeat="tblOpt in tableOptions">
    <a href="" ng-click="sortReverse = !sortReverse; order({{ tblOpt.sortTypeVal }},sortReverse)">
    {{ tblOpt.columnTitle }} 
      <span ng-show="sortType=={{ tblOpt.sortTypeVal }} && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
      <span ng-show="sortType=={{ tblOpt.sortTypeVal }} && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"></span>
    </a>
</th>
```

Ctrl:

```
var orderby = $filter('orderBy');

/*Sorting the columns*/
$scope.order = function (sortType, sortReverse) {
  $scope.nameslist = orderby($scope.nameslist, sortType, sortReverse);
};

/*Definition for TH-tags*/
$scope.tableOptions = [
  {
    columnTitle: 'Firstname',
    sortTypeVal: 'fname'
  },
...
]
```

I want to have the description in my Ctrl how you can see above in the example. Also the glyphicons don't displayed in the TH-Tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of `{{}}` inside `ng-click` or `ng-show`

Try this :

```
<th ng-repeat="tblOpt in tableOptions">
<a href="" ng-click="sortReverse = !sortReverse; order(tblOpt.sortTypeVal,sortReverse)">
{{ tblOpt.columnTitle }} 
  <span ng-show="sortType == (tblOpt.sortTypeVal && !sortReverse)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
  <span ng-show="sortType == (tblOpt.sortTypeVal && sortReverse)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: did you use like this `sortType == (tblOpt.sortTypeVal && !sortReverse)` ?

Comment: sorry it was a mistake myself.. I had the old Controller name!.. your solution is right!

Comment: Only I have one question. When I click on the TH-Tag then the glyphicon disappears. On the beginning when the page is loaded it is displaying the top glyphicon but normally when I have to click on the th-tag it must be displayed the bottom glyphicon?!

Comment: so, you want icon in bottom, on page load ?

Comment: no, I want to display the glyphicons when you click that the icon changed and not disappeared

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88463/discussion-between-gaurav-bhavsar-and-yuro).

Comment: Imagine you have 4 columns with TH-Titles.. The titles have corresponding glyphicons. that means if you don't click on a title the sortReverse is true and has the glyphicon css class `class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"`.. otherwise the sortReverse is `!sortReverse` and the css class is `...-bottom`.. look at the code above.. only the glyphicon top will displayed when the page is loaded. But after the click the glyphicon disappeared.

Comment: The Bootstrap glyphicon-triangle-bottom is available in the Version 3.3.3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815606/bootstrap-glyphicon-triangle-bottom-not-displaying